# Django Admin Custom Widget for ForeignKey

Tags: django, widget, foreign-keys, admin, django-hvad

*It sounds like a trivial question, but it seems not so easy to answer:*

How would you display a ForeignKey field as a Checkbox in Django Admin and save the currently logged in user whenever this user checks the checkbox in Admin?

Example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    approved = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

How would I be able to display the `approved` field as a checkbox?

Thanks alot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`get_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method on your ModelAdmin, and customize the form to what you wish.

In this case, you would have to change the fields widget to a checkbox, and set the value to request.user on form validation (if checked).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And you are sure Django's form cleaning methods dont block this approach?

Comment: Since you would have to implement the clean method for this field, it's all up to you. Not Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize it as follows in admin.py

```
class MyModelWidget(forms.ModelForm):
    approved = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelWidget)
```

Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 0):

In your form.py:

```
class YOURMODELForm(forms.ModelForm):
    approved = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.order_by('name'))
```